# How do I get out of the police car?

Tags: pc, the-walking-dead-season-one

I am stuck at the very beginning after the car crash. It says I should look around and find a way out of the car, but all I see are my handcuffs, a shotgun, and the dead police officer. I have no idea how to interact with my surroundings.

How am I supposed to get out of the police car?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kick the window on the other side

Comment: It seems my graphic card (Nvidia 7300GT) has issues with the game, as it does not show any interaction possibilities with the window. In fact, I barely can reckognize the interaction cursor, yet on the actual window, it is missing completely.